# Use id in aura:iteration for recordEditForm

Tags: lightning, aura, lightning-recordeditform, aura-iteration, aura-id

I have `aura:iteration` which goes through my custom wrapper class (which contains `List` of sObjects), and show `recordEditFrom` for all of them.

My wrapper does not have an `Id` field.
However, it has a key field (Something like this `Port 1, test product` ) that is unique.

And I have a custom submit button.

Here is my code :

```
<aura:component>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="item">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!item.Id}"
                              objectApiName="Custom_Object__c" 
                              onsubmit="{!c.onRecordSubmit}">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Custom_Field__c"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" aura:Id="!{item.key}" type="submit" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

So my questions are:

Do we have a possibility in the `onRecordSubmit` check on which button from the `aura:iteration` list we clicked?

I tried `aura:Id`, however, it can not be generated here

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It is recommended to copy-paste code as text, instead of the image for the question. If someone will try to replicate the behavior of your code, would be much easier to copy that from a question, instead of writing from an image.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi , Sorry, I agree with you, I have changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aura:id` can't be set dynamically via an expression. It is mentioned in the [Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm) documentation.

> aura:id doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal
> string values to aura:id.

at the same time, it is not required to be unique across the component. You can set `aura:id` as a string along with setting a custom `data-`. Custom `data-` dataset attribute supports expressions. So it will be storing a unique key for submit button.

**Howewer**, `data-` dataset is not supported in `lightning:recordEditForm`. In this case a workaround whould be to use `class` attribute, as when you click `submit` button, source of the event is a form:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="item">
        <lightning:recordEditForm
                aura:id="editForm"
                recordId="{!item.Id}"
                objectApiName="Custom_Object__c" 
                onsubmit="{!c.onRecordSubmit}"
                class="{!item.key}">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Custom_Field__c"/>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" type="submit" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

it is possible to get a source of the event in handler js controller:

```
onRecordSubmit: function(cmp, event, helper){
    const form = event.getSource();
    console.log('clicked form key: ', form.get('v.class'));
}
```

Comment: I have following error "The attribute "data-key" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:button"

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys please check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks you . it works now.